# Variable not being passed to view in cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

We are trying two forms that post to the same action.
We are trying to retrieve value of input field txt1 from first form and passing it to controller Lists where this value is being sent to be used in the for loop of the second form to dynamically create forms.
But this error is being shown:
"Undefined variable: counter [APP\View\Lists\add.ctp, line 107]
CakePHP: the rapid development php framework
CakePHP 2.6.1"
I am attaching the code for controller and view

View:

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {  

         $('#txtt1').on('change',function(){

             var paper=$(this).val();
                //alert('hello');
             if(paper<=0)
               alert('No of members should be greater than zero');
             if(paper!='')
               //$('#apap').hide();
         });
     });
</script>
<h2>Member Details</h2>

   <div id="post1">
</div>
<?php
echo $this->form->create('List',array('action'=>'add'));
echo $this->form->input('txt1',array('id'=>'txtt1'));
//echo $this->form->input('txt2',array('id'=>'txt2'));
echo $this->Js->submit('Enter No. of Panel Members: ',array('update'=>'#success','id'=>'apap','class'=>'butstyle'));

?>
 </div>           
<div id='success'>
<?php
$options =array('Mr.'=>'Mr.','Mrs.'=>'Mrs.','Ms.'=>'Ms.','Dr.'=>'Dr.','Prof'=>'Prof','Arch'=>'Arch'); 
echo $this->Html->script('jquery.min');

 for($i=1;$i<=$counter;$i++)
 {
    echo $this->form->create('List',array('action'=>'add','type'=>'file','id'=>'frm'));?>
  <?php
   echo $this->form->input('salutation',array('type'=>'select','options'=>$options,'empty'=>'--Select--'));?>

  <?php
 echo $this->form->input('name');?>
 <?php
echo $this->form->input('designation',array('type'=>'select','options'=>array($designation,'Others'=>'Others'),'empty'=>'--Select--'));?>
 <div id="y" style="display: none">
Designation:
<input type="text" id="txtx" name="data[List][desig_txt]"/>
 </div>
  <?php
   echo $this->form->input('specialization',array('type'=>'select','options'=>array($specialization,'Others'=>'Others'),'empty'=>'--Select--'));?>

  <div id="x" style="display: none">
  Specialization:
 <input type="text" id="txty" name="data[List][spec_txt]" />
 </div>

 <?php echo 
 $this->form->input('university',array('type'=>'select','options'=>array($university,'Others'=>'Others'),'empty'=>'--Select--'));?>
  <div id="w" style="display: none">
 University:
<input type="text" id="txtw" name="data[List][univ_txt]" />
 </div>
 <?php
echo $this->form->input('college',array('type'=>'select','empty'=>'--Select--'));?>
 <div id="z" style="display: none">
College:
<input type="text" id="txtz" />
 </div>


<?php
  echo $this->form->input('address');
    echo $this->form->input('phone');
echo $this->form->input('email');
  echo $this->form->input('papercode');
 //echo $this->from->checkbox('approved'); 
  echo $this->form->end('Save');
   ?>

    <?php } ?>


  </div>
```

Controller:

```
    function add($paper=NULL)
   {
        $this->loadModel('Designation');
        $this->loadModel('Specialization');
        $this->loadModel('University');
        //$this->loadModel('College');
        $this->set('designation',$this->Designation->find("list",array(
        'fields'=>array('desig_name','desig_name'))));
        $this->set('specialization',$this->Specialization->find("list",array(
        'fields'=>array('spec_name','spec_name'))));
        //echo $paper;
        $this->set('paper',$paper);
        $this->set('university',$this->University->find("list",array('fields'=>array('univ_name','univ_name'))));
        $this->set('counter','');
        if(!empty($this->data))
        {   //print_r($this->data);
            if(empty($this->data['Panel'][0]['name']))
            {    $count1=$this->data['Panel']['firstform'];
                 $count2=$this->data['Panel']['secondform'];
                 $counter=$count1+$count2;
                //print_r('llalla');
                  if($this->request->is('ajax'))
                  {  print_r($counter);
                     $this->set('counter',$counter);
                     $this->render('add','ajax');
                  }

            }

            else{
                print_r('balala');
                $counter=$this->data['Panel']['extra'];
                print_r('MR'.$counter);

                for($i=0;$i<$counter;$i++)
                {
                    print_r($i);
                    if($this->data['Panel'][$i]['designation']=="Others")
                    {
                        $desig=$this->data['Panel'][$i]['desig_txt'];
                        $this->loadModel('Designation');
                        $this->Panel->create();
                        $this->request->data['Designation']['desig_name']=$this->request->data['Panel'][$i]['desig_txt'];
                        $designationid=$this->Designation->find('count',array('fields'=>array('desig_id')))+1;
                        $this->request->data['Designation']['desig_id']= $designationid;
                        //print_r($this->request->data['Designation']['desig_name']);
                        if($this->Designation->save($this->request->data))
                            { echo "hello";}

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $desig=$this->data['Panel'][$i]['designation'];
                    }   
                    if($this->data['Panel'][$i]['specialization']=="Others")
                    {
                        $this->loadModel('Specialization');
                        $spec=$this->data['Panel'][$i]['spec_txt'];
                        $this->Panel->create();
                        $this->request->data['Specialization']['spec_name']=$this->request->data['Panel'][$i]['spec_txt'];
                        $specializationid=$this->Specialization->find('count',array('fields'=>array('spec_id')))+1;
                        $this->request->data['Specialization']['spec_id']= $specializationid;
                        //print_r($this->request->data['Specialization']['spec_name']);
                        if($this->Specialization->save($this->request->data))
                            { echo "hello";}
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $spec=$this->data['Panel'][$i]['specialization'];
                    }
                    //if($this->Designation->save($univ)){ echo "hello";}
                    if($this->data['Panel'][$i]['university']=="Others")
                    {
                        $this->loadModel('University');
                        $univ=$this->data['Panel'][$i]['univ_txt'];
                        $this->Panel->create();
                        $this->request->data['University']['univ_name']=$this->request->data['Panel'][$i]['univ_txt'];
                        $universityid=$this->University->find('count',array('fields'=>array('univ_id')))+1;
                        $this->request->data['University']['univ_id']= $universityid;
                        //print_r($this->request->data['University']['univ_name']);
                        if($this->University->save($this->request->data))
                            { echo "hello";}

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $univ=$this->data['Panel'][$i]['university'];
                    }
                    //if($this->Designation->save($univ)){ echo "hello";}
                    if($this->data['Panel'][$i]['college']=="Others")
                    {
                        $this->loadModel('College');
                        $college=$this->data['Panel'][$i]['college_txt'];
                        $this->Panel->create();
                        $this->request->data['College']['college_name']=$this->request->data['Panel'][$i]['college_txt'];
                        $collegeid=$this->College->find('count',array('fields'=>array('college_id')))+1;
                        $this->request->data['College']['college_id']= $collegeid;
                        //print_r($this->request->data['University']['univ_name']);
                        if($this->College->save($this->request->data))
                            { echo "hello";}

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $college=$this->data['Panel'][$i]['college'];
                    }

                    $this->Panel->query('insert into panels(salutation,name,designation,specialization,university,college,address,phone,email,papercode) values("'.$this->data['Panel'][$i]['salutation'].'","'.$this->data['Panel'][$i]['name'].'","'.$desig.'","'.$spec.'","'.$univ.'","'.$college.'","'.$this->data['Panel'][$i]['address'].'","'.$this->data['Panel'][$i]['phone'].'","'.$this->data['Panel'][$i]['email'].'","'.$this->data['Panel'][$i]['papercode'].'")');
                }   
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'panels','action'=>'index',$this->data['Panel'][$i-1]['papercode']));
            }


        }   
    }
```

Comment: Those conditions satisfied where you are setting `rd`?

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you. I think you are asking whether $this->data['List']['txt1'] contains the value or noot. I have printed this. It contains the value but the variable rd is not being passed to the view.

Comment: A few things to check:

* Is the code evaluating the part where the 'rd' variable is being set? 

* Since you are using $this->render() right after setting 'rd' all the content of #success will be overwritten, do you really want to do that?

* Get the latest version of DebugKit with support to AJAX requests and check the variables being set. 

* Check and post here the output from chrome developer tools (F12) panel.

NOTE: next time indent the code properly, please.

Answer (score 0):

You have set '$rd' variable when data goes to save .Means first time when page load then it does not go in your if condition

```
    if(!empty($this->data['List']['txt1']))
    { 
            echo 'kkl'; 
            if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax())
            {
                    echo 'dddd';
                    $this->set('rd',$this->data['List']['txt1']);
                    $this->render('add','ajax');

            }
        }
```

you should set 'rd' variable at the start of the function like this

`$this->set('rd','');`

Now rd variable will set in both condition even in page load or save data

Comment: I have changed the conditions in the controller but still not able to create the forms dynamically. The solution that you specified is also not working.

Comment: could you provide code of controller . according to current code i have provide solution

Comment: In your modified controller code you have not set '$rd' variable. Set it on start of function under counter variable

Comment: In my new code I have used $counter in place of $rd. But it is still not working and I have made the suggested changes.

Comment: But you have print $rd variable in view file. so please also change in view file

Comment: I have removed that line from my view file. And now it is not giving 'counter undefined' error. But still not creating forms. Can I have your email id so that I can share my code.

Comment: is it fix? if any queries plz let me know.